intellij idea plugins for kiwi TCMS
Could you please guide me on how to link Kiwi TCMS with IntelliJ IDEA so that I can execute my Selenium + TestNG automated tests from Kiwi? In other words, I'd like to select a scenario in Kiwi and then execute the corresponding automated script. Is there a plugin I can use for this, or any other suggested method?
